# invalid openssl verify signing chain in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, signing, pem, verify

Want to verify signing chain in nodejs by getting the certificate and the ca chain from sqlite databse, but it gives me the error 
Problem output:

> Error: Error: Invalid openssl exit code: 1 % openssl verify -CAfile
>   /tmp/ffb467bfe1d555e636b92d19a42ed914acd5a746
>   /tmp/bd47090d29fefccea28d66851f13c25c40d9819a Error loading file
>   /tmp/ffb467bfe1d555e636b92d19a42ed914acd5a746 usage: verify [-verbose]
>   [-CApath path] [-CAfile file] [-purpose purpose] [-crl_check]
>   [-no_alt_chains] [-attime timestamp] [-engine e] cert1 cert2 ...
>   recognized usages:    sslclient   SSL client  sslserver   SSL server
>     nssslserver Netscape SSL server     smimesign   S/MIME signing
>     smimeencrypt    S/MIME encryption   crlsign     CRL signing     any
>     Any Purpose     ocsphelper  OCSP helper     timestampsign   Time Stamp signing

in my nodejs file the code is:

```
db.getCert(uid, function(certificate) {
              if (certificate) {
                  var cert = JSON.stringify(certificate);
                  db.getCa( function(ca){       
                      console.log('ca test' +ca);
                      var cacert = JSON.stringify(ca);

                    pem.verifySigningChain(cert, cacert, function (err, result) {
                          if (err){
                             console.log('Error: '+err)
                          }  else{
                             console.log('Result: '+result)
                          }
                      return signingChain;
                    })
          })
              }else{
                  console.log('prob with cert')
              }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          res.send({error: error.toString() });
        }
```

is there a problem with the file format or that I get it from the database or something else?